# Date format in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

Hi I have this query in VFP however I don't understand the meaning of it

`REPLACE ALL varA WITH YEAR(varB)*100+MONTH(varB)`

Can anyone explain why YEAR(varB) is multiply by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at a PC to check but it looks like command will store yyyymm as a number. To achieve this, the command will store the year *100 (e.g. 202000) + month (e.g. 10 for October) = 202010. VarA stores a combination of date varB's year() and month () functions, both which return numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I been running my head around figuring why it is multiply by 100.

Comment: You're welcome. I just confirmed it with a simple command: 
? YEAR(DATE())*100+MONTH(DATE())